# Early sources for surface and bound charges in polarization

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, electricity

I am looking for early sources (references) to the analysis in electrostatics where the polarization vector is rewritten in terms of bound charges and a surface polarization charge.

In terms of what I have already found, the answer is nothing. All standard recent texts such as Griffiths just give a derivation without sources. The paper by Joan Bromberg (1968) DOI:[10.1119/1.1974442](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1974442) reasons that Maxwell himself did not do the surface and bound charges analysis, and an early textbook by N.R. Campbell (1913) *[Modern Electrical Theory](https://archive.org/details/moderntheoryelec00campuoft)* does not show it. My guess is that it appeared some time after 1913, but I may be wrong

Comment: It might help if you edit this to say what you have already found as otherwise people may waste time suggesting things you already know.